# html security profiling tools

Tags: html, security, firefox

I am developing a site and i am using yslow to profile speed and stats, webdeveloper for html and css validation, etc.

What can i use to check for security mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security I recommend the open source wapiti or the commercial [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About).

On a side note,  html and css can't really cause security problems.  Maybe if you have html links pointing to http content within https could be a problem and Sitewatch will inform you of of these problems.

Comment: what do you mean by "html and css can really cause security problems" ? Are you talking about allowing user html and css? i can see html causing a problem but not css.

Comment: actually you can execute javascript within css,  so that is still a problem.   HTML isn't an issue but,  `<script>` tags are.  You can also use onload= and onmouseover=  to do nasty things with other html tags.  By in large filtering `<>` is a very good idea.

Comment: html can be a problem if you link to http resources from an https page.  browsers will throw an warning and acuentix will detect this.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Review [this list](http://sectools.org/web-scanners.html).

Obviously what is relevant is your server-side language (so you may want to scan from the WEB side and then an analysis of the server code as well).

This is a significant field of work and research. It's good that you want to perform this type of analysis, and enjoy reviewing and testing all the various available tools :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use free tools like [Netsparker Community Edition](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/) or [Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/)

You can also refer to this list of free and commercial web app security scanners:
http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246988/Web-Application-Security-Scanner-List

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your site you could possibly use a tool called [Fortify](http://www.fortify.com/). It will scan your code for security vulnerabilites. I am sure there are other tools which are similar.

Comment: Sorry but fortify is not for web apps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with OWASP Top 10 (http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project). You can try rat proxy (http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/) - it is a security audit tool. Other http/https proxies such as paros also can to some extent detect injection and XSS flaws.

None of these is perfect and so with a good understanding of web application vulnerabilities you can supplement with some manual tests and code inspection.